# Error on launching a local version of a website

Tags: jekyll

I tried to install Jekyll On Windows 7. I followed this guide http://www.testically.org/2012/02/02/installing-jekyll-and-ruby-on-windows/
So I first downloaded Ruby and added     \;C:\Ruby193\bin to the path variable. 
I then downloaded DevKit and added     \;C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband\bin\     to the path variable as well. 
I then opened my command and did the following (in order)
    cd ;C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband
    ruby dk.rb init
    ruby dk.rb install

the following are the codes that appeared on my screen when I did the above steps.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jimmy>cd ;C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband

C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby193'

C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband>gem install jekyll
Successfully installed jekyll-0.12.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-0.12.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for jekyll-0.12.0...

C:\Users\jimmy\Downloads\teeheeband>
```

Once I did the above, I downloaded github and cloned the repo that I wanted to work on. I then went to Gitshell and did the following

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jimmy\Documents\GitHub> cd  prog694.github.com
C:\Users\jimmy\Documents\GitHub\prog694.github.com [new-branch]> jekyll --server
 --auto
Configuration from C:/Users/jimmy/Documents/GitHub/prog694.github.com/_config.ym
l
Auto-regenerating enabled: C:/Users/jimmy/Documents/GitHub/prog694.github.com ->
 C:/Users/jimmy/Documents/GitHub/prog694.github.com/_site
[2013-02-03 20:19:00] regeneration: 402 files changed
[2013-02-03 20:19:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-02-03 20:19:01] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-01-15) [i386-mingw32]
[2013-02-03 20:19:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4036 port=4000
[2013-02-03 20:20:24] ERROR no access permission to     `/'
jimmy-PC - - [03/Feb/2013:20:20:24 Atlantic Standard Time] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403
283
- -> /
[2013-02-03 20:20:24] ERROR `/favicon.ico' not found.
jimmy-PC - - [03/Feb/2013:20:20:24 Atlantic Standard Time] "GET /favicon.ico HTT
P/1.1" 404 281
- -> /favicon.ico
```

Finally I opened a browser and tried to run a local copy of the website via : localhost:4000 
I failed and got this message

```
Forbidden

no access permission to `/'
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-01-15) at 127.0.0.1:4000

so I used h**p://127.0.0.1:4000/( replace t with **)
```

failed again

```
Forbidden

no access permission to `/'
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-01-15) at 127.0.0.1:4000
```

All I want is to be able to open and run a local version of this website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth you're running a pre-release version of Jekyll. You might see if you get better error messages (or if the issue goes away entirely) with Jekyll 1.0+. As a basic debugging step, see if the `_site` directory is being created at all, and see if the files generated therein look right.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your port 4000 is not used by something else, or if you have a firewall enable access to it.

I'd highly disrecomend Windows for jekyll (or any ruby gem/app), installing and using it in Linux would be much easier.